# Program does not use all cores

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, ansi-c

I have a complex program which should use all cores to perform complex math calculations.

I have a system with two *Intel Xeon Platinum 8160*. Each of them has `24 cores` so together I have `48 cores` and `96 threads`.

My program only uses `24 cores` and not all `48`. It works on the `24` of the first CPU or the `24` of the second one but not all together.

When I start a second instance of the program, then nothing changed only one CPU is used.

I attach some screenshots.

[image]

I extracted some code to a minimal working example, which checks how many threads are available. Only `48` are detected and not all `96 threads`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <process.h>

static void thread_start(void *thread) {
    int i;
    i = *(int*)thread;
    for (;;) {
        i = (int)sqrt(i++);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    SYSTEM_INFO sysi;
    int thread_max, i;

    argc = argc;
    argv = argv;

    GetSystemInfo(&sysi);
    thread_max = sysi.dwNumberOfProcessors;

    printf("\n... thread_max=%d\n", thread_max);

    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < thread_max *2; i++) {
        _beginthread(thread_start, 0, &i);
    }

    for (;;) i = i;

    // return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

[image]

My Machine runs under *Windows 10 64-bit Pro*. What could be the problem?

Comment: what does the set affinity in task manager say?

Comment: what is set affinity?

Comment: @Felix [Thread Affinity is the ability to tell the OS that you want a thread scheduled on a particular core if possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadaffinitymask)

Comment: where can I check that?

Comment: A machine with that many cores uses a numa architecture, separate processor chips each with their own memory bus, glued together with an interconnect that is needed when data needs to be shoveled from one to the other.  Enshrined in the winapi as well, albeit for a different reason, these processors are organized into separate groups.  Each group can't have more than 64 cores.  You are only using one group and therefore can see only half of the cores.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/processor-groups

Comment: Task manager -> details => right click on the process

Comment: each process is by default assigned to exactly one group

Comment: @HansPassant how can I use both groups?

Comment: You probably shouldn't, that interconnect can very easily turn into a significant bottleneck.  Google "numa programming techniques" to find the tools you need to do it correctly.  I'll volunteer my machine to swap with yours, another very easy fix :)

Comment: ;) and what is the reason for when I run two instances of the same exe the second one does not use the idle 24 cores?

Comment: an further hints?

Answer (score 0):

`GetSystemInfo` and `dwNumberOfProcessors` return the number of processors in the current group, not the total number of hardware processors. [See Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/ns-sysinfoapi-system_info)

> The number of logical processors in the current group. To retrieve
> this value, use the GetLogicalProcessorInformation function.

You should instead call `Get­Active­Processor­Count` with the `ALL_PROCESSOR_GROUPS` parameter. This counts up all processors across all groups.  As recommended by [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200824-00/?p=104116)